# Can't resolve 'react-native' when trying to use react-native-community/slider

Tags: reactjs, react-native, node-modules, package.json

I have an import at the top of one of my React components that breaks the app. This is the import `import Slider from "@react-native-community/slider";`
and this is the error.

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-native' in 'C:\Users\Cody\OO\Bug-Fixes\Wellness\client\node_modules\@react-native-community\slider\dist
```

I have tried countless commands to install react-native-community and I do see it in node_modules, but I still get this error. This path seems correct to me and it does exist `'C:\Users\Cody\OO\Bug-Fixes\Wellness\client\node_modules\@react-native-community\slider\dist` but not sure why it is looking for 'react-native` in that path.

This is my package.json folder:

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.25",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.11.2",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.5",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "^3.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.8.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "query-string": "^6.8.3",
    "react": "^16.10.1",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^1.0.3",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.12",
    "react-bootstrap-typeahead": "^3.4.7",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^2.8.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.10.1",
    "react-gauge-chart": "^0.2.5",
    "react-infinite-scroller": "^1.2.4",
    "react-moment": "^0.9.2",
    "react-quiz-component": "^0.2.7",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.0",
    "react-share": "^3.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "throttle-debounce": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8080",
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.18.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.15.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: try rm -rf node_modules and install node modules again with command npm install

Comment: I just tried, Still the same error :(

Comment: you'll need `react-native` for this to work. i suggest you search for another slider based on `reactjs` instead.

Comment: hey can you check your react-native version

Comment: In the package.json or run a command?

Comment: Oh this isn't compatible is what you are saying? @kenmistry

Comment: @mastercool is this a react project or react native ? You cannot use react native packages in react projects i think

Comment: Oh i did not know that. I guess it is a react project. How can I tell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://react-component.github.io/slider/?path=/story/rc-slider--handle

https://www.npmjs.com/package/rc-slider

Try this react package for your react project instead current one